# Convert Base 10 to Base 36 Using a Formula

Tags: excel, math

Is there an easy way to convert a number from Base 10 to Base 36 in Excel?  I have a list of over 2,000 numbers that I need to convert so I can't do it one by one in one of the online converters.

I was thinking even if there is a mathematical way of doing it I can use a formula.

Answer (score 4):

A better solution would be to use the BASE function

=Base(number to convert,base)

eg

=base(35,36)   = Z

=base(36,36)   = 10

Comment: The second answer is usually best!

Comment: This will not work for older versions of Office. The BASE function (and its counterpart the DECIMAL function) was introduced in Excel 2013 and is not available in earlier versions of Excel.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this:

http://www.thetropicalevents.com/Xnumbers60/
http://www.thetropicalevents.com/Xnumbers60.htm

[Added the code as requested by Korem]

or

```
Sub main()
    Dim base10Number As Double
    base10Number = Int(Rnd * 1000)
    Debug.Print base10Number, ConvertBase10(base10Number, "0123456789ABCDEF")
End Sub

Public Function ConvertBase10(ByVal d As Double, ByVal sNewBaseDigits As String) As String
    Dim S As String, tmp As Double, i As Integer, lastI As Integer
    Dim BaseSize As Integer
    BaseSize = Len(sNewBaseDigits)
    Do While Val(d) <> 0
        tmp = d
        i = 0
        Do While tmp >= BaseSize
            i = i + 1
            tmp = tmp / BaseSize
        Loop
        If i <> lastI - 1 And lastI <> 0 Then S = S & String(lastI - i - 1, Left(sNewBaseDigits, 1)) 'get the zero digits inside the number
        tmp = Int(tmp) 'truncate decimals
        S = S + Mid(sNewBaseDigits, tmp + 1, 1)
        d = d - tmp * (BaseSize ^ i)
        lastI = i
    Loop
    S = S & String(i, Left(sNewBaseDigits, 1)) 'get the zero digits at the end of the number
    ConvertBase10 = S
End Function
```

Copied from http://www.freevbcode.com/ShowCode.asp?ID=6604

or similar....

```
=ConvertBase10(A1,"0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ")

Sub main()
     Dim MyNumber As Double
     MyNumber = 999999999999999#
     MsgBox MyNumber & ": " & ConvertBase10(MyNumber, "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ")
End Sub

Public Function ConvertBase10(ByVal d As Double, ByVal sNewBaseDigits As String) As String
     Dim S As String, tmp As Double, i As Integer, lastI As Integer
     Dim BaseSize As Integer
     BaseSize = Len(sNewBaseDigits)
     Do While Val(d) <> 0
         tmp = d
         i = 0
         Do While tmp >= BaseSize
             i = i + 1
             tmp = tmp / BaseSize
         Loop
         If i <> lastI - 1 And lastI <> 0 Then S = S & String(lastI - i - 1, Left(sNewBaseDigits, 1)) 'get the zero digits inside the number
         tmp = Int(tmp) 'truncate decimals
         S = S + Mid(sNewBaseDigits, tmp + 1, 1)
         d = d - tmp * (BaseSize ^ i)
         lastI = i
     Loop
     S = S & String(i, Left(sNewBaseDigits, 1)) 'get the zero digits at the end of the number
     ConvertBase10 = S
End Function
```

Copied from: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/microsoft.public.excel.worksheet.functions/yY7U_kX_FwU

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback Korem